# Qu'est-ce qui fait qu'un verbe tienne tout seul, comme jouer vs calibrer?

Tags: choix-de-mot, syntaxe

Quel méchanisme de la langue française est reconnue de manière implicite lorsque la phrase suivante semble incomplète, mais pas lorsqu'on remplace calibrer par jouer:

"Laisse moi calibrer." vs "Laisse moi jouer."

Qu'est-ce qui différencie jouer de calibrer ?

Merci

Answer (score 6):

Le verbe **calibrer** est strictement transitif direct, il prend obligatoirement un COD (sauf s'il décrit un état dans un contexte implicite).

En revanche, **jouer** peut être transitif indirect **ou** intransitif, selon le contexte. Il peut donc être utilisé seul.

**edit:** Pour approfondir sur ce que j'ai appelé "contexte implicite", on peut voir qu'en français la transitivité des verbes est une chose très fluctuante — un exemple plus généraliste : **manger** est un verbe transitif direct,

> Le chat mange la souris.

Malgré cela, il peut être utilisé comme verbe transitif indirect (usage plus poétique, mais correct) :

> Nous mangeons à nos amis disparus.

Et même, pour revenir à la question, comme verbe intransitif (ou plutôt pour être pédantique, comme verbe transitif sans complément) :

> Tu peux venir m'aider ? — Non, je mange.

Ou même :

> Tu fais quoi ? — Je mange.

Il décrit ici un **état** (qui se traduit par un présent progressif qui est identique au présent simple en français, mais par exemple pas en anglais où le participe présent serait utilisé avec l'auxiliaire être) dans ce que j'appellerais un **contexte implicite** (je n'ai pas trouvé de nom "officiel" pour ce que je décris). Contexte, car "Je mange" tout seul n'a pas vraiment de sens, alors que s'il est précédé d'une question comme ici, on comprend sa fonction d'état. Implicite, car rien n'a besoin d'être ajouté à aucune des deux phrases pour mettre en évidence ce contexte.

*Sources: dictionnaire de l'Académie française ; Larousse*

Comment: Serait-il possible d'avoir plus de clarifications sur ce qu'est un contexte implicite et sur ce qu'est un état dans un contexte implicite ? Ce que j'en comprends, c'est que ce contexte provient de la phrase dans laquelle le verbe a été utilisé uniquement. Par exemple, dans "laisse moi me calibrer" il est compris un sens tel que "je vais me ressaisir, me poudrer, me mettre au point". Par contre, dans "laisse moi calibrer", même si le contexte externe de la phrase était la mécanique, la phrase "laisse moi calibrer" ne tiendrait pas toute seule.

Comment: @L4mbo Je ne suis pas linguiste mais en tant que natif, la phrase "Je calibre" ne me semble avoir de sens que si elle est précédée d'une question du type "Que fais-tu?". Dans ce cas là, supposons que le patron veuille seulement savoir ce que fait le mécanicien, sans pour autant manifester d'intérêt pour la cible précise de l'action de ce dernier. Mais je reconnais que quelque chose semble différencier *jouer* de *calibrer*. Peut-être que *calibrer* semble plus "précis" et requiert donc plus souvent un complément, tandis que jouer peut informer d'un "état d'action" plus général.